# how to increase length of edges when plotting a graph in R

Tags: r, plot, igraph

Is there a way to plot a graph in r with bigger edge lengths?
I am simply using

library(igraph)

plot(graph)

and do anybody knows why all the edges have variable length?

```
**    V1    V2
1      6     1
2      6     5
3      1     0
4      1     6
5      1   385
6      5     4
7      5     6
8      5    98
9      0     1
10     0     2
```

I have data in this format and I am generating a network graph.

[image: Click this link to see the graph]

Comment: Do you mean the margins beside the plot?

Comment: no I mean the length of lines connecting two nodes?

Comment: Provide a rep. example.

Comment: i wanted to post the picture but the website does not allows me to do so

Comment: A picture won't help. Copy and paste a minimal example your code if you want a suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

You could try a few things:

You could change the margins on your plot:

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(graph)
```

You could change the layout parameters by exploring the igraph documentation on [layouts](http://igraph.org/r/doc/layout_.html) to do things like:

```
test.layout <- layout_(g,with_dh(weight.edge.lengths = edge_density(g)/1000))
plot(g, layout = test.layout)
```